# Rewrite or delete existing .png file in IOS swift apllication

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I would like to add the text on my .png image which exist in my swift application and REPLACE my old image with this edited image.
But when I am trying to remove old image I am getting the error message :

```
          Error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“Background.png” 
          couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it." 
        UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57134C17-50A5-
    4709-9E3B-8013733175BA/SignatureApp.app/Background.png, NSUserStringVariant=(
                Remove
            ), NSUnderlyingError=0x12cd8c150 {Error 
Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

Code which I am using to remove my old png file is :

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Background", ofType: "png")!

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
do {
    try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Can anybody give an idea how is it possible to rewrite or delete existing .png file in IOS swift aplication?

Comment: How did you set that image initially? Using Image Assets in Xcode, right? So replace that file in imageAssets with new file.

Comment: No it is not in Image Assets, It is in Xcode directly, for that solution I cannot use Image Assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this. The image is part of your app bundle. You would need to upload a new application.

Instead you could store the image in the documents or cache directory and in your code check if that file exists and load it instead of `Background.png`.

Comment: This is the approach you should take.  You can even write the new path your app should use to `NSUserDefaults` if you need to.  This will also let you generate multiple images from scratch, in case, you know, your user changes whatever value you're superimposing.